# Is this scenario appropriate for a singleton?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Quick question, I've been programming objective-c for about 2 months now, however I am well versed in a number of other languages.

I would like to know if the following situation is appropriate for a singleton, and if so, is there a more appropriate way of handling the initialization of the singleton than my current code?

I have the singleton, enemiesArray that is accessed by a multitude of other classes. This is in my Enemy class, enemy is the direct parent of a number of enemy specific classes. Each enemy specific class accesses initWithSpriteFile during it's own initialization, which in turn adds the enemy to the enemiesArray singleton.

```
// Singletons
static NSMutableArray *enemiesArray;

// Methods
+(NSMutableArray *) sharedEnemies
{
    if (!enemiesArray) { enemiesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; }
    return enemiesArray;
}

+(id) initWithSpriteFile:(NSString *) spriteFile;
{
    if (!enemiesArray) { enemiesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; }

    if ((self = [super spriteWithFile:spriteFile])) {
        [enemiesArray addObject:self];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: SO is not intended for code optimization ...

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Are enemies CCNode objects (like CCSprite)? Then storing these in a singleton brings with it the very real danger of memory leaks because you might still hold references to a scene's nodes when changing scenes. That would keep the previous scene in memory. You should put that code in your scene's class instead. No need to use a singleton here.